# Displaying a video using OpenCV 2.4.1

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi i tried to display a video using webcam using following basic commands
in opencv 2.4.1 :-

```
int main()

{ cv::Mat san;

  cv::VideoCapture san_cap(0);

  while(1)
  {
    san_cap.read(san);

    cv::imshow("gp",san);

    if(cv::waitKey(0) >=0)

      break;
  }

   return 1;

  }
```

during compilation i dont get any error but while running my solution my output video stucked on a fixed frame and in my console i was having following error :-

**VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument**

on line by line debbuging my code i found out i m getting error in this particular line

```
if(cv::waitKey(0) >= 0)
```

what can be the error in this line???

Comment: The error isn't in this line, that's just the event loop that triggers all the updates. VIDIOC_QUERYMENU means the camera driver got bad data.

Comment: but when i commented this line i don't get any error

Comment: when you comment out this line opencv doesn't display any images!

Comment: @MartinBeckett i replaced my line **if(cv::waitKey(0) >=0)** with            **if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 )** and it worked.....anyway thnks for ur help :-)

Comment: waitkey(10) pauses for 10ms before trying to draw the next image, that probably gives the video driver time to complete something  - I was going to suggest just putting a delay in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do with the `cv::waitKey()` but I think your example should work if you change it to this. As mentioned the waitKey should be set to something like 10 and you should always check if the videoCapture is actually open. If it can not be opened it is a problem with your hardware/driver/os/OpenCV install.

```
int main() {

    int waitKeyValue = 10;
    cv::Mat san;

    cv::VideoCapture san_cap(0);
    if (san_cap.isOpened()) {
        while (1) {
            san_cap.read(san);
            cv::imshow("gp", san);
            int key = cv::waitKey(waitKeyValue);
            if(key!=-1)cout<<key<<endl;
            if (key == 27 || key == 1048586) {
                if (waitKeyValue == 10)waitKeyValue = 0;
                else waitKeyValue = 10;
            }
        }
    } else cout << "videoCapture not working" << endl;
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: with `if(cv::waitKey(10)&255)==27)` i want that whenever i press **ENTER** key the video stops

Comment: My answer (although untested) should work. cv::waitkEy returns an integer that you can check and use to set the waitKey itself again.

Comment: i tried ur code but i was not able to stop video after pressing **ENTER** key....u can see my comment on my question that condition loop worked fine...thnx

Comment: Ah you're right, I see you fixed the problem already. If anyone else needs it in the future I fixed my code now that I had a chance to compile. It now works with pausing the frames on ENTER key as well.